# Just another infinite resistor ladder - question

Tags: sequences-and-series

I am currently playing around with infinite resistor ladders.
The goal is always to find an equivalent resistor to the ladder network.
This particular specimen (see link) is giving me major headaches.
Any suggestions how to approach it.

[image: The problematic Infinite Resistor Ladder]

Comment: Please make the question in a way that will ensure it is understood even after your given link is dead.

Comment: I think the biggest thing here is to find out which resistances are in parallel... if I read the picture right, you have $1$ in series with $1$ which is in parallel with $.1$ in series with $10$ which is parallel with...  The approach I would take is to make a finite series up to some $n$, then increase $n$ by one and see what happens.